What's the role of the embedded question in this sentence?

サイズが合うかどうか着てみます。

As I understand it, the "サイズが合うかどうか" part is an embedded question (疑問節) meaning "whether the size fits or not", but I fail to understand how the embedded question is connected to the rest of the sentence.
The following is my analysis:

I don't think the embedded question is the object of "着て" (with the "を" particle omitted), because you wear clothes, not a question. I think the object of "着る" is implied by the context.
Maybe it's the topic of the sentence, with "は" particle omitted?


サイズが合うかどうか is not the topic of the sentence because inserting は does not make sense to me. And it's not the object of 着る, either (you correctly described why).
This か-clause is not tightly connected to the other parts of the sentence. In my opinion, it's something like a comment that works independently even if it looks like a noun phrase. Japanese embedded questions ending with か can be used in the beginning or middle of a sentence to insert a question as an "aside":

How to use ~のか accurately? 「体調が悪いのか、顔色があまり良くない。」
What does からか mean?
Unsure about this usage of か
Is ためか the same as ために?

I think we can understand the syntax of your sentence as an extension of these. It may be still a type of noun phrase, but in terms of its usage, it behaves somewhat like an independent question enclosed in parentheses or dashes in English text.

After reading your answer and posts you linked (thanks! really helpful), I think the "サイズが合うかどうか" part can be understood as a separate clause (節) indicating a doubt. It might be slightly clearer with a 読点 inserted? "サイズが合うかどうか、着てみます。" Translate to: Does the size fit or not?/How's the size? Try it on. I think your answer have solved my question. Thank you.

@Naitree Yes, it's perfectly natural to put a comma there, although it's not necessary at all.
